# Problem switching nRF24L01 module with MOSFET

Tags: arduino, stm32, nrf24l01

I am trying to switch [nRF24L01 module](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/297/NRSAS00020_1-2559917.pdf) with MOSFET to reduce power consumption as low power mode for nRF24L01 is not working.

My setup includes STM32G030F6P6TR without external crystal. So, when I put the MCU to shutdown mode and wakeup with watchdog reset the nRF24L01 doesn't send signal on wake up. It works with other low power modes of MCU. But if I connect the nRF24L01 power line directly to 3.3 V it works even with shutdown mode of MCU.
It also works when connect base of the transistor directly to 3V(even with the shutdown mode).
I have already placed a 22 μF capacitor on the power line of nRF24L01 module.

Below is the MOSFET circuit.

[image: MOSFET switching circuit]

Here's the code. I am using Arduino IDE to program the STM.

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include "STM32LowPower.h"
#include <IWatchdog.h>

#define MOSI PA7
#define MISO PA6
#define SCK PA1
#define mosfet PA4
RF24 radio(PA12, PA11);  // CE, CSN pins
const byte address[6] = "00001";

void setup() {
    SPI.begin();
    SPI.setMOSI(MOSI);
    SPI.setMISO(MISO);
    SPI.setSCLK(SCK);

    pinMode(mosfet, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(mosfet, LOW);

    Serial.begin(115200);

    radio.begin();
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);  
    radio.setRetries(3, 15);        
    radio.openWritingPipe(address);

    IWatchdog.begin(10000000);
    LowPower.begin();
    radio.powerUp();
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(mosfet,HIGH);
    delay(50);

    if (radio.write(state, sizeof(state))) {
        //radio.powerDown(); 
        digitalWrite(mosfet,LOW);
        delay(50); 
        LowPower.shutdown();
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the part number of your MOSFET ?

Comment: Mosfet: SI2305
Transistor: BC547

Comment: Your MOSFET appears to be logic-level-gate so it should turn on with a logic-HI from MCU. Did you measure the voltage across the drain and GND to see if it turns on properly? Are you certain that you placed the MOSFET correctly/properly?

Comment: Yes it turns on. The problem only occurs when I use LowPower.shutDown()
With other low power modes it works. Also, It works with LowPower.shutDown() only when I connect Vcc of nrf directly to 3V

Comment: Add an exact schematic.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIIL7.png

rest nothing so fancy. nrf is connected to the pins as mentioned in the code. STM is running on internal clock. caps on power line.

Comment: You wrote, when it fails _"[the nRF24L01] doesn't send signal on wake up"_. From your error description, I fail to see if it's a hardware or firmware issue. Have you figured it out?

Comment: No still working on it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks every one. Problem solved. The nRF initialisation code was in setup which was not setting up the module after reset as the vcc was disconnected from the module on restart(MOSFET was off). Moving the nRF initialisation code to loop fixed the problem.